# How can I capture the node label or value at runtime for bubbles chart using bubble::renderBubbles

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am creating bubble plot using library(bubbles) in r and shiny.

I get the plot but my requirement is I should be able to capture the value in each node when user clicks so that I can create my next plot based on this input.

How can I plugin the javascript to get the desired output.

Appreciate any help on this.

ui.R

bubblesOutput("Plot", width = "100%", height = 600)

server.R

output$Plot <- renderBubbles({

```
df <- datadf[,c("A","B")]

df$B<-as.numeric(df$B)

bubbles(value=df$B, label=df$A, key = df$A,color = rainbow(length(count), alpha=NULL))
```

})

Comment: not sure if this is the easiest way but you can get plot click as input value in bubblesOutput `bubblesOutput("Plot", click = "plot_click")` and define the range corresponding to the input value. More info over here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html

Comment: bubblesOutput do not have this input parameter